# How can I use multiple \extrainfo?

Tags: moderncv

I'm writing my resume with `moderncv`, and I'm trying to put a second `\extrainfo`, but when I do it, the first disappear. There is no link between first and second.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using `\extrainfo` multiple times (which it's not designed for), have you tried using line breaks inside its argument?

[image]

Code (compiled with `xelatex`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{oldstyle}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\name{Tristan}{Best}
\title{Curriculum~Vitae}
\address{%
  Apt 1, Mt Everest,
  Best street,
  Bestcity,
}{}{Bestland}
\phone[mobile]{+353(0)858180441}
\email{}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[github]{tristan}
\extrainfo{%
  extra info 1 \\
  extra info 2
}
\quote{Look no further: I'm the best!}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Experience}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted to do it with the casual theme.
So, inspired by an answer, inspite of trying to use \extrainfo{arg1}{arg2} (or other syntax) I used \extrainfo{arg1 \footersymbol arg2}. And it works. Thanks for helping =)

Comment: I tried \\ and doesn't work for me. I get an unknow error in the console

Comment: @JaredLo Please be more specific. What doesn't work? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Jubobs I am using banking style, here is the error i got `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` maybe it doesn't work anymore. found the answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261282/92620 but how if I want to break line?

Comment: Works for me and plus I laughed at the "look no further I'm the best" part, +1

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Tristan's comment, I successfully fixed this issue by using `\footsymbol` instead of `\footersymbol` in `casual`. I'm using version 2.0.0 (28 Jul 2015) of `moderncv`.

Here is my example of the usage of `\extrainfo` with multiple arguments:

`\extrainfo{Born on DD.MM.YYYY \footsymbol Single \footsymbol Swiss}`