# How to use \extrainfo several times in modern banking cv template?

Tags: moderncv, links

Currently I'm using the [modern banking cv template](https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/cover-letters/moderncv-banking). The problem is that I would like to add `\extrainfo` several times, for instance like this:

```
\extrainfo{\href{link}{\textit{extra}}}

\extrainfo{\href{https://github.com/johndoe}{\faGithub~john doe}}
```

The template does not allow me to use the `\extrainfo{}` macro more than one time. For example:

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')


\usepackage{fontawesome}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage[scale=0.90]{geometry}


% personal data
\name{\LARGE{john }} {\LARGE{doe}}
\title{\LARGE{Statement of Purpose}}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\extrainfo{\href{www.google.com}{\textit{link}}}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\extrainfo{\href{https://github.com/johndoe}{\faGithub~johndoe}}

\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{}
\closing{Yours faithfully}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle



\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

[image]

How can I add several **additional information** bullets more times?.

**Update**:
I tried the Gonzalo Medina approach, although he seems to have the correct output I got both links layed off ass follows:

[image]

**Update**
With [this version](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv) I got the following output:

[image]

And this exceptions:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty, line 27

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.27 \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| A font might not be found for many reasons.
| Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.
| 
| When in doubt, ask someone for help!
|...............................................
moderncv/examples/moderncvbodyiii.sty, line 85

Undefined control sequence.

<argument> \tiny \faCircleO 

l.85 ...dth{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
moderncv/examples/spo.tex, line 27

Undefined control sequence.

\mobilephonesymbol ->{\Large \faMobile 
                                       }~
l.27 \makelettertitle

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
moderncv/examples/spo.tex, line 27

Font EU1/FontAwesome(0)/m/n/10.95=FontAwesome: at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.

<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.27 \makelettertitle

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
moderncv/examples/spo.tex, line 27

Undefined control sequence.

\emailsymbol ->{\small \faEnvelopeO 
                                    }~
l.27 \makelettertitle

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
moderncv/examples/spo.tex, line 27

Font EU1/FontAwesome(0)/m/n/10=FontAwesome: at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.

<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.27 \makelettertitle

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
moderncv/examples/moderncvheadiii.sty

You have requested package `moderncvheadiii',
moderncv/examples/moderncvbodyiii.sty

You have requested package `moderncvbodyiii',
moderncv/examples/spo.tex, line 27

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 27--27
```

I also tried adding the `fontawesome` font but still the same.

Comment: Without a mwe it is harder to answer your question.

Comment: And can you use the `fontawesome` package at all? Is it installed, e.g.?

Comment: In TL 2014 a command like  \faMobile  will not work, as this is a new symbol. So you should update the font *and* the style-files from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome/tex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use one `\extrainfo` command and add there all the information you require, using `\makeheaddetailssymbol` between entries if you want the usual separator between the various informations:

```
\extrainfo{\href{www.google.com}{\textit{link}}\makeheaddetailssymbol \href{https://github.com/johndoe}{\faGithub~johndoe}\makeheaddetailssymbol additional information3}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale=0.90]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{\LARGE{john }}{\LARGE{doe}}
\title{\LARGE{Statement of Purpose}}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{\href{www.google.com}{\textit{link}}\makeheaddetailssymbol \href{https://github.com/johndoe}{\faGithub~johndoe}\makeheaddetailssymbol additional information3}

\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}

\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{}
\closing{Yours faithfully}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

\end{document}
```

The resulting title:

[image]

### Update

For older versions (those in TeX Live2014) of `moderncv`/`fontawesome`, here's the required code (the idea is the same but in older versions `\makeheaddetailssymbol` was `\maketitlesymbol`):

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{\LARGE{john }}{\LARGE{doe}}
\title{\LARGE{Statement of Purpose}}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{\href{www.google.com}{\textit{link}}\maketitlesymbol\href{https://github.com/johndoe}{\faGithub~johndoe}\maketitlesymbol additional information3}

\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

The document has to be processed using xelatex or lualatex and the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I update the status of the question since the link and the github url are layed off, any idea of why this is happening?.

Comment: @ml_guy Do you get the output in the image using the exact code in my answer? Do you have the latest moderncv version installed?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried the same code on sharelatex and I used this version of the [moderncv](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)

Comment: You can get the latest `moderncv` version from ctan: [`moderncv`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv). I don't know if ShareLaTeX has the lates versions of packages.

Comment: And with the *exact* same code in my answer (not parts of it plasted into your actual document) and that version of `moderncv` you get the output in your image?

Comment: Thanks gonzalo, yes I tried exact the same code of your answer. However, with the version that you provided me I got the above output (I updated the status of the question)

Comment: @ml_guy Try compiling with XeLaTeX?

Comment: Yes and with lualatex

Comment: I also got: `Undefined control sequence.

\@extrainfo ...xtit {link}}\makeheaddetailssymbol 
                                                  \href {https://github.com/...
l.27 \makelettertitle
                   
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
`

Comment: Please follow this link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26949/discussion-between-ml-guy-and-gonzalo-medina to a chat room, so we can discuss there.

Comment: @ml_guy I just tested the second version of my answer (the one for older packages) in ShareLaTeX and using xelatex it worked as expected (just some warnings about fonts).