# tikz standalone does not show drawn arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I drew some arrows to annotate a figure using standalone. However, when I put in [tikz]{standalone} the arrows do not show. If I use report or remove the [tikz] then the arrows show up, however, I want the figures to be separate on their own pages. How can I achieve this? Thanks for your time.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,backgrounds}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}


\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture] 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=south, inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{./graphics/imdligand.pdf}};
\node [anchor=west] (ligand) at (3,2.9) {2x L\textsubscript{IMD}};

\node [anchor=east] (top) at (0.35,4.56) {};
\node [anchor=east] (bottom) at (0.98,1.29) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path [line,black,thick] (ligand) |- node {}(top);
\path [line,black,thick] (ligand) |- node {}(bottom);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south,inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{./graphics/pyrligand.pdf}};
\node[anchor=west] (ligand2) at (3,4.3) {2x L\textsubscript{PYR}};

\node[anchor=east] (top1) at (0.85,5.9) {};
\node[anchor=east] (bottom2) at (0.85,2.6) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path [line,black, thick] (ligand2) |-node{}(top1);
\path [line,black,thick] (ligand2) |-node{}(bottom2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to put the arrows in the same `tikzpicture` as the figure they belong to as each `tikzpicture` will get its own page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `tikzpicture` starts a new page when you use the `tikz` option for the `standalone` class. This prevents the `overlay` picture from ever appearing, as there is nothing for it to be overlaid on.

To avoid this, simply include the arrows in the `tikzpicture` environment of the relevant figure.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% \tikzstyle is deprecated
  line/.style = {draw, -latex'}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [anchor=south, inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
  \node [anchor=west] (ligand) at (3,2.9) {2x L\textsubscript{IMD}};
  \node [anchor=east] (top) at (0.35,4.56) {};
  \node [anchor=east] (bottom) at (0.98,1.29) {};
  \path [line,black,thick] (ligand) |- node {}(top);
  \path [line,black,thick] (ligand) |- node {}(bottom);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=south,inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}};
  \node[anchor=west] (ligand2) at (3,4.3) {2x L\textsubscript{PYR}};
  \node[anchor=east] (top1) at (0.85,5.9) {};
  \node[anchor=east] (bottom2) at (0.85,2.6) {};
  \path [line,black, thick] (ligand2) |-node{}(top1);
  \path [line,black,thick] (ligand2) |-node{}(bottom2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: non-overlay overlaid arrows]

Comment: oh great, silly me. thanks for spotting that out.

Comment: Can I bother you with something? If you can run the document in [`this answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261282/3954) it runs with some warnings using xelatex but pdflatex fails with errors related to `fontawesome`. I am not familiar with that package, but I've used it without problems in other sitiuations. Do you have any idea where the problem is?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Not quite sure that I really got what you are referring too. But the undefined ` \faMobile ` is simply due to an outdated package. It doesn't work in TL14. This symbol has been added later.