# How to add a newline inside \extrainfo while using banking style?

Tags: moderncv

I am using `moderncv` with [banking style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstylebanking.sty), I want to be able to add a new line inside `\extrainfo`.

ps: I already saw ["How to use \extrainfo several times in modern banking cv template?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261282/92620) which show how to add multiple extra infos within `\extrainfo` but with no ability to add a new line, also i saw "[How can I use multiple \extrainfo?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194208/92620)" but the answer doesn't work for banking style.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\name{Name}{Name}
\title{Curriculum~Vitae}
\address{%
  Apt 1, Mt Everest,
  Best street,
  Bestcity,
}{}{Bestland}
\phone[mobile]{0000000000}
\email{}
\homepage{www.site.com}
\social[github]{github}
\extrainfo{%
  extra info 1
  extra info 2
}
\quote{Look no further: I'm the best!}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Experience}
\end{document}
```

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31110714#31110714

Answer (score 2):

The line breaking of the info content depends on the size (width) of the content. If you want `extra info 1` and `extra info 2` to be on their own line, make sure you place it in a box that's wide enough. Below I've used `tabular` and padded the left/right with a `2em` space. Inside the `tabular` you're able to break the line using `\\` as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\name{Name}{Name}
\title{Curriculum~Vitae}
\address{%
  Apt 1, Mt Everest,
  Best street,
  Bestcity,
}{}{Bestland}
\phone[mobile]{0000000000}
\email{}
\homepage{www.site.com}
\social[github]{github}
\extrainfo{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{2em}}c@{\hspace{2em}}}
    extra info 1 \\ extra info 2
  \end{tabular}
}
\quote{Look no further: I'm the best!}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Experience}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use e.g. a tabular or a \parbox:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\name{Name}{Name}
\title{Curriculum~Vitae}
\address{%
  Apt 1, Mt Everest,
  Best street,
  Bestcity,
}{}{Bestland}
\phone[mobile]{0000000000}
\email{}
\homepage{www.site.com}
\social[github]{github}
\extrainfo{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}extra info 1\\
  extra info 2\end{tabular}
}
\quote{Look no further: I'm the best!}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Experience}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Besides the fact it's not a practical solution, whta to do if i want `extra info 1` in a new line, not in the same line as social infos.